# Electron: DevTools makes application FASTER?

Tags: dom, webkit, google-chrome-devtools, electron

I have electron app i'm developping; I face a strange behaviour which I would like to benifit.

I have a div element thats with overflow:auto, and, inside it, I have a lot of elements. When scrolling with mouse and trackpad, it is kinda choppy, but with the scrollbar it's not.

But as I'm developping it, I noticed that if I open my DevTools once, the app gets smoother, even after it get closed. So my conclusion is: Opening developper tools makes electron faster.

But my app is not going to be in Développement forever. What does opening dev tools triggers that could be triggered by my app?

EDIT
Finally DevTools was resizing the window making it faster). After Investigation, I changed

```
win.maximize();
win.webContents.on('did-finish-load', (e) => {
    win.show();
})
```

for that (which fixed my app)

```
win.webContents.on('did-finish-load', (e) => {
    win.show();
    win.maximize();
})
```

Comment: This can only be caused by a bug in Electron/Chromium (could be reported already) or your app (you can try divide-and-conquer debugging to find what's causing it).

Comment: No it was way easier than that: Opening devtools triggers a window resize event in my app... have to investigate further though!

EDIT